# Cannot insert string in SQLite table but can numbers

Tags: php, sqlite

Can naybody tell me what this means

```
INSERT INTO users
             (first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) 
             VALUES ('s',1,1,1,1,1);
```

but when I try

```
INSERT INTO users
             (first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) 
             VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

it works. I cannot insert string ? What is wrong ?
My SQLite table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE users (
      id          integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      first_name  varchar(50),
      last_name   varchar(50),
      email       varchar(50),
      username    varchar(50),
      password    varchar(50),
      privilege   varchar(50)
    );
```

and my PHP function looks like

```
public function insert_user($first_name, $last_name
                      , $email, $username
                      , $password, $privilege) 
{
try {
    $db = new SQLite3($this->db_path);

    $db->query(
"INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) 
    VALUES($first_name,$last_name,$email,$username,$password,$privilege);");

     $last_id = $db->lastInsertRowID();
     $db->close();
     return $last_id;
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Exception caught: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$username','$password','$privilege');")
```

Missing a ' around the variables. Might want to escape values first.
Debugging tip: Put your query into a variable, echo that variable and try it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you need to turn

```
     VALUES($first_name,$last_name,$email,$username,$password,$privilege
```

into

```
     VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$username','$password','$privilege' )
```

MySQL/PHP accept numbers without the ''s, but not strings. Also, you might want to escape your input using a default PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use '..' with strings in VALUES

```
 $db->query("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$username','$password','$privilege');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to insert data using SqliteManager? I mean do you know that problem was caused from php script or database. If you try to run your query on sqlitemanager. Also try to use "s" with ( " )not ( ' )